# Computed property not evaluating when component is loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a `maps` component that is initializing a google map, adds markers to that map according to props which are passed from a parent and then sets the correct bounds of the map. However, those markers are added through a computed property as I want it to be reactive. Actually everything works well, except that the `addMarkers` function within my computed properties seems to be not evaluating when the page and therefore the component is loaded.

Now the strange thing about it: when I open Vue Devtools and click on the `maps` component, `addMarkers` immediately evaluates and changes the map correctly.

Any help highly appreciated :-)

```
<template lang="pug" >

div.google-map(id="results-map")

</template>
<script>

import Gmaps from 'gmaps';

export default {
    name: 'maps',
    props: {
        results: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            map: {},
            bounds: {}
        }
    },
    computed: {
        addMarkers() {
            this.results.forEach((result) => {
                if (result.latitude && result.longitude) {
                    var marker = this.map.addMarker({
                        lat: result.latitude,
                        lng: result.longitude,
                        title: result.name,
                        infoWindow: {
                            content: result.name
                        }
                    });
                }
                this.bounds.extend(marker.position)
            });
            this.map.fitBounds(this.bounds)
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.map = new Gmaps({
            div: '#results-map',
            lat: 0,
            lng: 0,
            zoom: 15
        });
        this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A computed property is supposed to **return a value** while your `addMarkers` does not return any value.

Furthermore, a computed property is only computed at the moment you require it. So the fact that it is not showing the markers at the creation of your component is that the computed property is never required.

However, when you open the dev tools, VueJS tries to evaluate that computed property and executes the code. And your code adds the markers, but it is not a computed property.

So you have different solutions here.

Either you try to force the evaluation of your computed property on the `mounted` hook:

```
mounted() {
    this.map = new Gmaps({
        div: '#results-map',
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0,
        zoom: 15
    });
    this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    this.addMarkers
}
```

Or you make a method of your addMarkers and execute it whenever you want:

```
import Gmaps from 'gmaps';

export default {
    name: 'maps',
    props: {
        results: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            map: {},
            bounds: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addMarkers() {
            this.results.forEach((result) => {
                if (result.latitude && result.longitude) {
                    var marker = this.map.addMarker({
                        lat: result.latitude,
                        lng: result.longitude,
                        title: result.name,
                        infoWindow: {
                            content: result.name
                        }
                    });
                }
                this.bounds.extend(marker.position)
            });
            this.map.fitBounds(this.bounds)
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.map = new Gmaps({
            div: '#results-map',
            lat: 0,
            lng: 0,
            zoom: 15
        });
        this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        this.addMarkers()
    }
}
```

For example, if you want to rerender the markers when `results` is changed, you can use the `watch` property:

```
export default {
    ...
    watch: {
        results: {
            deep: true,
            handler () {
                this.addMarkers()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers for your detailed answer, works like a charm. I didn't know that computed properties are always supposed to return a value – I'm still new to Vue!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the `addMarkers` computed property anywhere. I think you want to change that to a method instead, and call it during your `mounted` function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to react to `results` changing from *outside* your component:

- Turn the `addMarkers()` computed property, into a **watcher** on `results`.

This will make sure the code is **executed** everytime the `results` prop **changes**.

Also, since you are running some DOM manipulation logic in your `mounted()` hook:

- Wrap the logic of the `results` watch inside a [**`Vue.nextTick()`**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) to make sure it is executed when the DOM is ready to be changed (aka after you configured `<google-maps>`):

> [**`Vue.nextTick()`**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick): Defer the callback to be executed after the next DOM update cycle. Use it immediately after you’ve changed some data to wait for the DOM update.

So, your watch would (which used to be `addMarkers()` computed property) becomes:

```
watch: {                                                                 // line changed
    results: {                                                           // line changed
        deep: true,                                                      // line changed
        handler () {                                                     // line changed
            Vue.nextTick(() => {                                         // line changed
                this.results.forEach((result) => {
                    if (result.latitude && result.longitude) {
                        var marker = this.map.addMarker({
                            lat: result.latitude,
                            lng: result.longitude,
                            title: result.name,
                            infoWindow: {
                                content: result.name
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    this.bounds.extend(marker.position)
                });
                this.map.fitBounds(this.bounds)
            });                                                         // line changed
        }                                                               // line changed
    }
},
```